# Linux routing: routing between 2 local interfaces depends on source address?

Tags: routing, ipv4, linux, udp, interface

The setup is this:
The linux system (debian 7 as a VBox guest) has the following interfaces:

```
$ ip addr
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
        link/ether 08:00:27:de:a3:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 201.1.1.1/24 brd 201.1.1.255 scope global eth0
    3: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 500
        link/ether 9e:7a:83:ec:5e:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 10.0.0.1/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global tap0
```

The routing table is populated by a quagga ripv2 daemon and look as follows:

```
$ ip route
10.0.0.0/24 dev tap0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1 
201.1.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 201.1.1.1 
202.1.1.0/24 via 10.0.0.2 dev tap0  proto zebra  metric 2
```

UDP packets are received from another subnet through interface tap0. Their destination is always 201.1.1.1:30000.
However, depending on their source address, some of them will be seen or not by a netcat listener.
This is the tcpdump output:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -i tap0 port 30000
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tap0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
17:25:36.060532 IP 10.0.0.2.38353 > 201.1.1.1.30000: UDP, length 6
17:25:52.073758 IP 202.1.1.1.30000 > 201.1.1.1.30000: UDP, length 457
```

And netcat output:

```
$ netcat -vnulp 30000
listening on [any] 30000 ...
connect to [10.0.0.1] from (UNKNOWN) [10.0.0.2] 38353
hello
```

The 1st packet (len 6, sent with netcat) is correctly received. The 2nd packet (len 457, sent with a datagram socket bound to 202.1.1.1) is not received.
What should I do to have both packets be correctly received by netcat?

notes: iptables are empty ; /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward=1

Comment: Why can't you bind your program to more than one interface?

Comment: I replaced the program with a `netcat -ul` and updated the question: same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The second packet is sourced from an adjacent subnet which appears to have been learned via Quagga (this information would be relevant in your OQ). The `tap` interface has obviously received the packet, which `tcpdump` is showing you, but it hasn't been handed up the stack to your application.

The `length` of each packet also gives some clues. Why is the second packet so much larger than the first? Does it contain additional information that your application is not parsing correctly?

Also, the fact that the `tap0` interface is in state `UNKNOWN` is also problematic - it should be in the `UP` state. You could try to bridge `tap0` and `eth0` together (which is how `tap` interfaces are traditionally utilized), and then move 201.1.1.1/24 to the newly created `br0` interface.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sorry I oversimplified the context: indeed, eth0 and tap0 have static ip ; the routing table is learnt by a quagga ripv2 daemon ; the daemon successfully exchange through the tap0 interface, which suggests that the state of tap0 is not causing the problem.

Comment: The first packet is much smaller because it was sent for testing with `echo hello|netcat 201.1.1.1 30000`, from another subnet.